# How should I build a base floor for a large summerhouse?

Tags: concrete, subfloor, shed

Hi my question has 2 parts about piles and creating a subfloor.

I want to install a 4.8x4.8m (~16'x16') summerhouse; its existing floor is 24mm (~1") floor boards on 75x50mm (~"2x3") floor posts.

I don’t want a concrete base so I thought I could create my own piles using 110mm (~4.5") pipe (filled with postcrete and topped with damp-proof membrane) for the sub floor to rest on.

Is 110mm (~4.5") good enough or should I get 150mm (~6")? How deep should I go with the piles and at what spacing.

I then want to create a base frame for the summerhouse to go on and was thinking that as it already comes with a 75x50mm (~"2x3") floor I could create another one (joist running the opposite way) with 75x50mm (~"2x3") timbers.

Are these good enough timbers for the sub floor as I don’t want to go too high either? what spacing should I have between them?

Comment: Can you define 'pile'? I think that term might mean something slightly different from region to region.

Comment: It really depends what kind of soil this is going in.  Where are you at and has the soil been undisturbed?

Comment: @DA01 "Pile" is an accurate term, but you might think of it as a foundation "pier". In essence, columns that extend underground to create foundation points. Most often used for underpinning/foundations of decks and sheds, or in addition to standard foundations either where support columns will be located above or where unstable grade would pose a problem, in residential construction.

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're asking.  Do you have an already constructed house that you want to move to a new location?

Comment: @JacobS that makes sense. I've always heard the term "piling" but now that I think about that, that's just the plural of pile. ;)

Comment: Thanks Da01, great explanation. Basically I am going to make columns out of the concrete filled pipes and rest a base floor on them. The house has its own floor that will in turn rest on the sub floor. Im thinking that the house has a 75x50 batons so if I create another 75x50 base with the joist in the opposite direction at 600 centres  that would be solid!!! Any thoughts
Also how far apart should I put the piles/piers. The ground is heavy clay in West Sussex.
I have the house but in bits, like flat packed,

Comment: To my mind, it would be working backwards to proceed with a pile approach. But I do hear you regarding wanting to stay out of concrete. Concrete has a huge carbon/energy footprint and is problematic to demo and dispose of, even more so if you place rebar. Instead of piles, I'd create a raised bed of gravel and set the existing 75x50 floor directly on top of that. By raised bed I mean boxing in the perimeter above grade with, say, 2x4s or 2x6s, then tamping down the gravel. Well that's assuming the area doesn't flood.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this guide. step-by-step and easy to follow!**  http://www.gardenbuildingsdirect.co.uk/blog/build-a-shed-base/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged here. Providing a summarized overview with a reference link is a much better option to minimize lost content due to dead links.